# Calling a parent function from a child component raises an error in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a navigation drawer child component inside my parent component.

**MainComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
<v-app>
<div>
    <NavigationComponent></NavigationComponent>
</div>
</v-app>
</template>
```

Now, in the child component (Navigation drawer), I tried to call a function from the `MainComponent` by doing:

```js
this.$parent._appendUser(arr);
```

I have a similar parent-child component that calls a function from parent to child, but I don't know why this one gives me an error saying:

> TypeError: this.$parent._appendUseris not a function

**Parent Component - MainComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
<v-app>
<div class="container" style="padding: 0 !important">
<div class="row">
</div>
<AddInstrumentDrawer :add_instrument_drawer_watcher="add_instrument_drawer_watcher"></AddInstrumentDrawer>
</div>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
import AddInstrumentDrawer from './shared/AddInstrumentDrawer.vue'

export default {
    name: 'user-profile',
    components: { AddInstrumentDrawer },
    data: () => ({
        profile_image_drawer_watcher: 1,
        add_instrument_drawer_watcher: 1,
    }),
    methods: {
        appendinstrument(arr) {
            alert(arr);
            /*for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                this.profile_data.instruments.push(arr[i]);
            } */
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```html
<template>
<v-app>
<div>
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="add_drawer" fixed temporary right width="600"
        disable-resize-watcher disable-route-watcher
        style="z-index: 101 !important">
    <div class="drawer-footer">
        <div class="drawer-footer-content-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn mx-1" @click="test()">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</v-navigation-drawer>
</div>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
    
export default {
    name: 'add-instrument-drawer',
    components: {  },
    props: ['add_instrument_drawer_watcher'],
    data: () => ({
        add_drawer: false,
    }),
    watch: {
        add_instrument_drawer_watcher: function(n, o) {
            this.add_drawer = !this.add_drawer;
        },
    },
    methods: {
        test() {
            this.$parent.appendinstrument('test');
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: please share the code of child component and the parent methods

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I edited and provided the code. I hope its useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call parent method using `this.$parent.someMethod()` but you have to `emit` a custom event from child component to the parent one which has the parent method as handler :

```
   <AddInstrumentDrawer 
     @append-instrument="appendinstrument"

     :add_instrument_drawer_watcher="add_instrument_drawer_watcher"></AddInstrumentDrawer>
```

in child component :

```
    methods: {
        test() {
            this.$emit('append-instrument','test');
        },
    },
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've been using `this.$parent.function()` but this is the first time it didn't work. can you explain why tho?

Comment: You should respect the flow between component, parent component pass props to child one and the child emit an event to update a parent properties, please check this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to call parent methods from child component.  Components should not be aware of  parent implementation. I suggest you emit an event in your navigation drawer and handle the event in your main  component

```
//Navigation.vue

$emit('append-user', arr)
```

```
//Main.vue
<Navigation @append-user="appendUser" />
```

This way you can place your navigation component within any component.

One more thing about **$parent** is that it does not reference the component that includes the target but the immediate component in the component tree where component is placed (think about DOM traversal)

```
//Main.vue
<ComA>
   <ComB />
</ComA>
```

Inside **ComB** $parent will reference **ComA**
and not Main component